# Prove that $|A| =|\mathbb Z|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{ (2n,-3n)~|~ n\in \mathbb Z\}$. Prove that $|A| =|\mathbb Z|$.

So to clarify this, I have to find a function that is bijective between $A$ and $\mathbb Z$ to prove that the cardinality of $A$ and $\mathbb Z$ is the same.

What would an example of a function, $f:A\to \mathbb{Z}$? Would it be something like $f(x,y)$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The most natural function is from $\mathbb Z$ to $A$ and is given exactly by the definition of $A$.

Comment: @GitGud so $f(x)=(2x, -3x)$?

Comment: Try it instead of asking. Is it surjective? Is it injective?

Comment: Alternatively, $A\subset\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ implies $|A|\leq|\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{N}|$.
Since $A$ is not finite, the reverse inequality follows (though this
is probably not in spirit with what you are learning).

Comment: @Alfredo Did you manage to conclude anything?

Comment: @GitGud I believe that function is injective, surjective is proving to be more difficult.

Comment: Injective: For a contrapositive $f(x)=f(y)$, $(2x,-3x)=(2y,-3y)$, $(x,x)=(y,y)$

Comment: @Alfredo Surjection is the easy part, but I understand why you'd be confused. I'll spell it out for you. You want to prove that $\forall a\in A\exists x\in \mathbb Z(f(x)=a$. So take an arbitrary $a$ in $A$. (Keep in mind that you want to find a suitable integer $x$). By definition of $A$ this means that $a=(2n,-3n)$, for some integer $n$. Set $x:=n$. Then $f(x)=f(n)=(2n,-3n)=a$, more specifically $f(x)=a$, as desired. End of proof.

Comment: @Alfredo This may seem long for something I said was the easy part, but most people would just say "It's surjective by construction", because you're defining the image of $f$ exactly as the definition of the elements of $A$. The injection part is correct, but I'd write things differently.